# Cyclic groups of integers

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography, cyclic-groups

I am trying to implement the Regev cryptosystem, but I have trouble with some symbols. For example, what exactly is:
$$
{\mathbb {Z}}_{q}^{n}
$$

I know it's something about cyclic groups etc but for example, what does it mean for given q=11 (modulo) and n=3 (order)? How can that be a distribution to choose uniformly at random?

Comment: It means $(\Bbb Z/q\Bbb Z)^n$.

Comment: ${\mathbb Z}_q$ often means the group of integers under addition modulo q. The upper index, I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@paf is correct, in the context of lattice crypto $\mathbb{Z}^n_q = (\mathbb{Z} / q\mathbb{Z})^n$.

An element in $\mathbb{Z}_q^n$ is simply an $n$ dimensional vector of integers modulo $q$. So to answer your second question, to generate a uniformly random such element, you just independently choose $n$ values uniformly at random from the integer range $[0,q)$.

Comment: +1. Note that $\mathbb{Z}^n_q$ is *not* the same as $\mathbb{Z}/(q^n)$, although they have the same number of elements. Also, note that the notation "$\mathbb{Z}_n$" conflicts with the standard notation for the [$p$-adic integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number).

Comment: Nice. Totally understandable now. I thank you from here because my upvotes aren't seen publicly at the moment.